# Create new item for each user from people picker column

Tags: 2013, jquery, designer-workflow, spservices, people-picker

In list A, there is column A which is people picker that allows multiple entries, there are also additional columns, B, C, ..
What I want to create is, when user populates columns and enters in people picker column multiple values, I want to create as many new items as there are users in people picker column.

So, if he enters three values in people picker, I want three new items in same list, same values to all columns except to people picker column, where instead of multiple values now there will be unique values of people from original item.

Any suggestion if this is achievable in SPD2013 workflow?
I guess I could do separation of users with SPServices or some other client side jquery script writing, but than my whole concept of creating new items via SPD workflow is out of game.

*Not able to use Infopath nor Visual studio.*

Comment: What's the reason you need an item per person?

Comment: Request of customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I went around different sites and looked for function how to split string in SPD workflow 2013. After it, everything went smoothly.

In Loop I looked for **;** in my string value, because no matter what was return output type, login or email. Read somewhere that with IDs it won't work.
After this I set **IF** clause to check if my string value is grater than 0, this had to be done to go from beginning til the end of string value and to go through all **;** characters.

Than I extracted part of string until 1st **;** and stored it to new variable.
Than I had to increment my counter (the string value), than I copied part of string after 1st **;** and stored it again to same variable.
Else clause was necessary to leave Loop.

At the end I added Create item action and there on people picker column I added my string variable in which I stored every value.
I tried with both email and login output types, but email gave me some problems, like not forwarding me value in people picker column, so I stayed with login output and it was good to go.  Bellow is print screen of WF.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use SPD Worklow, Get the people picker value as email address separated by semicolon and assign it to Workflow variable, then using loop with condition and string action in 2013 you can get individual email and then create a item,

but if you are having 250+ characters in user string this will fail.